# How to recognize operators in a string

Tags: c#, .net, operators

If i have string like this:

```
string a = "<=1.0.5" or "=1.0.5" or "!=1.0.5";
```

How can i get the part with operator and the part with version number separately into variables?

Comment: Well is the string *always* operator then version number? If so, just find the first digit and split that way...

Comment: If they always come in the way you supplied you can check if it starts with a number or a symbol. And just keep looping and appending to a variable that till the system detects a number. Then you have the operator in that variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some kind of regex:

```
var str = "=1.0.5";
var regex = new Regex("([<>=!]+)(.*)");
var result = regex.Match(str);
Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[2].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

If equal operator always present in the string:

```
string a = "<=1.0.5"; // "=1.0.5" or "!=1.0.5" or "==1.0.5"
int indx = a.LastIndexOf('=') + 1;  
string op = a.Substring(0, indx);  //<=
string version = a.Substring(indx); //1.0.5
```